# How to switch to gui-less vmware session in XP?

Tags: windows-xp, vmware-workstation, scheduled-task

I have a scheduled task that runs a vmware session in the middle of the night (this in turn does a task from our legacy server).  Last night, it did not complete.  Is there a way to attach to the running vmware session?  This occurs intermittently, and I'd love to know why it actually fails.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what version of vmware you're using and the operating system of the VM. If the VM is windows xp or later, I'd recommend just using remote desktop to log into the thing. If the VM is some sort of unix, you have a lot more options, like using ssh to get a shell, VNC, or running an X11 server on your non-VM machine. Of course, all of that assumes the VM is available on a network you can see from your usual desktop system.

If you're using vmware server 1, you can also install it on the system you want to connect from. Then you can tell the vmware client to connect to a remote system (the one hosting the VM).

If you're using vmware server 2, you can just point your web browser at the system you installed vmware on (assuming you know what port the vmware admin gui is running on), log into that remotely, install the vmware plugin for your web browser, and then reconnect again (after you restart your web browser) and get into it that way. The methods for vmware server 1 and 2 assume you can reach the system hosting the VM over the network.

I'm not familiar with other versions of vmware, sorry, but I suspect similar methods are available for connecting to them.

Comment: All fantastic suggestions, sadly none of them will work in my case.  The guest is Win2k, but I'm 99% certain that it's not even booting all the way (as otherwise, it is configured to immediately start a log - and there's no log).  And I wish I was lucky enough to be running vmware server - unfortunately, workstation was so much cheaper, and like most people, my boss only sees cost at outset.  BUT, like I said, otherwise good suggestions.

Comment: @Nate I believe george was talking about the free vmware server product http://www.vmware.com/products/server/ not ESX(i)